# MYSQL show latest few rows, but display the results in an ascending order

Tags: mysql

I'm using this query

```
SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
```

It shows the latest three notes displayed as follow:
Note 24, Note 23, Note 22

What I'm trying to do is to display the results as follow:
Note 22, Note 23, Note 24.
Any Ideas ?

Comment: Yes! We will be happy to help you with your homework!  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Reorder the resulting rows by re-selecting them, but this time use `ASC` order (the default):

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3) x
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM notes ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3)
AS t ORDER BY t.id ASC;
```